# java.lang.IllegalAccessError when running code

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm in the process of making an application in Java that loads and displays an X3D model, and I've downloaded all the correct `jars` and placed them in the project and I can see each of the classes that each of the `jars` contains. However, when I run my code in NetBeans, I get the following error:

```
No skin defined in xj3d-skin.properties
Producing default properties.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.j3d.aviatrix3d.ViewEnvironment.<init>()V from class org.j3d.aviatrix3d.surface.BaseRenderingProcessor
    at org.j3d.aviatrix3d.surface.BaseRenderingProcessor.<init>(BaseRenderingProcessor.java:223)
    at org.j3d.aviatrix3d.surface.RenderingProcessor.<init>(RenderingProcessor.java:49)
    at org.j3d.aviatrix3d.surface.SimpleAWTSurface.<init>(SimpleAWTSurface.java:95)
    at org.web3d.ogl.browser.X3DBrowserJPanel.<init>(X3DBrowserJPanel.java:264)
    at org.web3d.ogl.browser.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.createComponent(X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.java:249)
    at org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:252)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:43)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:59)
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

The java code that I have for the project at time point is shown below:

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","MEDIUM");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","MEDIUM");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","LOW");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.web3d.ogl.browser.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Component browserComponent = (Component)    x3dComponent.getImplementation();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(browserComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"test.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see from the error message that I'm receiving, I'm getting an exception that's `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` and I'm wondering how I'd go about fixing it. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The following list is all the jars that I'm using.

```
aviatrix3d-all
aviatrix3d-all_2.2.0
aviatrix3d-core
aviatrix3d-glsl
aviatrix3d-utils
dis-enums
gnu-redexp-1.0.8
httpclient
j3d-org-all_3.0.0-nps
jogl_old
uri
vecmath
vlc_uri
xj3d-common_2.0.0
xj3d-config_
xj3d-core_2.0.0
xj3d-ecmascript_2.0.0
xj3d-external-sai_2.0.0
xj3d-j3d
xj3d-java-sai_2.0.0
xj3d-jaxp_2.0.0
xj3d-net
xj3d-norender_2.0.0
xj3d-ogl
xj3d-parser_2.0.0 
xj3d-render_2.0.0 
xj3d-runtime
xj3d-runtime_2.0.0
xj3d-sai_2.0.0
xj3d-sav_2.0.0
xj3d-script-base
xj3d-script-base_2.0.0
xj3d-xml_2.0.0
```

**EDIT #2**

I've done the modifications and I've downloaded the `xj3d-2.1 installer` and put it into a library and put it in the project. And my code looks like the following.

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","MEDIUM");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","MEDIUM");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","LOW");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"test.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the run time error that I'm getting now is:

```
Feb 27, 2016 10:00:03 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BrowserConfig:  PrimitiveQuality must be low, medium or high
    at org.xj3d.sai.BrowserConfig.initialize(BrowserConfig.java:355)
    at org.xj3d.sai.BrowserConfig.<init>(BrowserConfig.java:240)
    at     org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.createComponent(X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.java:211)
    at     org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:263)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:42)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:   Java returned: 1
```

Comment: When you say 'all the correct jars', exactly which JARs do you mean?  The exception message in your question suggests to me your JAR versions are inconsistent.  Please edit your question to include a list of all JARs you are using, along with their versions.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I've just updated the question.

Comment: I've had a look through some of the aviatrix3d and Xj3D JARs I could find and I can't find any classes in the package `org.j3d.aviatrix3d.surface`.  I also get next to no Google search results for such classes.  Do you know which of your JAR files contains, for example, the `BaseRenderingProcessor` class that appears in your stacktrace?  Among your JARs you have some with no version number and some with the same name and a version number (e.g. `aviatrix3d-all` and `aviatrix3d-all-2.2.0`).  Is it possible that those with no suffix are old versions?

Comment: When I've looked inside the package `org.j3d.aviatrix3d.surface` within Netbeans, the following are found. `BaseRenderingProcessor, DebugAWTSurface, DubugRenderingProcessor, ElumensRenderingProcessor, ElumensAWTSurface, QuadBufferStereoRenderer, Renderer, RenderingProcessor, SimpleAWTSurface, SingleEyeStereoRenderer, StereoAWTSurface, StereoRenderer` which are all classes. And the jars without the suffix are old versions which I have in because the new ones don't have all the classes that the old ones have and vise versa

Comment: @LukeWoodward I'm still wondering why it isn't working

Comment: Are you developing in windows 8.1 or windows 10 platform?

Comment: The current OS on my laptop is windows 8.1

Comment: @smitthy: my suspicion is that there are two copies of the ViewEnvironment class among your JARs.  One of them has the constructor public, the other package-private.  When asked to load this class, Java happens to choose the one with the package-private constructor. However, the BaseRenderingProcessor class has been compiled against the one with the public constructor.  So when the BaseRenderingProcessor class tries to call this constructor, Java throws the IllegalAccessError because the constructor is package-private, and one class cannot call another's package-private constructor.

Comment: @LukeWoodward So should I get rid of the `jars` that are duplicates? And I'm guessing that I need to use the jars that are listed in the `Setting up the environment` section of the following link? [link](http://www.xj3d.org/tutorials/xj3d_application.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've got something working.

It looks like your code was written to work with Xj3D 1.  I made a few modifications to the code to get it working with Xj3D 2.  Firstly, change the line that calls `System.setProperty` to the following:

```
        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
```

The idea to make this change was taken from [here](http://objectmix.com/vrml/192048-%5Bx3d%5Dproblem-simplesaidemo.html).

Secondly, the values of the parameters `TextureQuality`, `PrimitiveQuality` and `Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality` need to be in lower-case, not upper-case as they are at the moment.

Thirdly, it turns out that the `X3DComponent` that gets returned by the call to `BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent` is a subclass of `JPanel`, so it can be added directly to the `Container` without needing to call `getImplementation()`.  Delete the line

```
        Component browserComponent = (Component)    x3dComponent.getImplementation();
```

and replace the line

```
        cp.add(browserComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

with

```
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Finally, you need to use the following five JARs, all of which are provided by the xj3d-2.1 installer which can be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xj3d/files/installers/):

- xj3d-2.1-3rdparty-nps.jar
- xj3d-2.1-nps.jar
- jogl-all.jar
- joal.jar
- gluegen-rt.jar

After making these changes I was able to use your `Xj3DTest` class to view an X3D file.  I don't have your `test.x3dv` file so I used [the X3D file on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D#Example).  Your class appeared to work for me – I'm using Java 1.8.0_60 x64 on Windows 10 x64, if that helps – but it wasn't without its issues:

- It takes about two minutes for the window to open.  I don't know what it's doing in this time.  Process Explorer shows two `jogamp_exe_tstNUMBERS.exe` processes, each of which runs for about a minute.
- The following message (exception stack trace omitted) appears after the two minutes:

  ```
  SEVERE: Native code library (32 and 64 bit library) failed to load: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no odejava in java.library.path
  ```

  If you can find a binary version of the odejava library then you are doing better than me.  Still, the program appears to work without it.
- The following messages appear a number of times just before the window opens.  Again, I'm not sure why but they don't appear to do any harm:

  ```
  Message: Attempting to make GL context current again in order to initialise the surface
  Error: The GL context failed to initialise for some mysterious reason
  ```
- The program doesn't quit cleanly: I have to kill the java.exe process from Process Explorer after closing the window.

Comment: So if I make those modifications to the code, and download those five jars and place them within the same library as the jars that are listed in the question, it should work? Or should I delete the duplicates of the jars?

Comment: @smitthy: get the others out of the way.  Just use those five.  They were all I needed.

Comment: So get rid of all the jars that I have already downloaded and only have those 5 you've listed?

Comment: @smitthy: in short, yes.  The important thing is to make sure that your NetBeans project has only those five JARs I listed as libraries.  I was able to run the modified version of your code from the command line with only those five JARs on the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: I've managed to find the `gluegen-rt.jar`, `joal.jar` and the `jogl.all.jar` but I'm struggling to find the other two jars

Comment: @smitthy: if, as I wrote in my answer, you run the xj3d-2.1 installer, then you will find that it will create all five JARs for you.  The installer asks for an installation path and puts all the JARs in a `jar` subfolder within that path.

Comment: I've posted an answer in this question as I have an error message I don't understand

Comment: @smitthy: that error message means that Xj3D doesn't like the value of the `PrimitiveQuality` parameter in the line `requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","MEDIUM");`.  I wrote in my answer what to do about this, and two other parameters: change the values to lower-case, e.g.  `requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");`.